# In a Task trigger, is there any way to know if a Task is an Email before it has been inserted?

Tags: trigger, email, activity

In the "before insert" section of my Task Trigger, I want to check if a Task is an email. But from what I can tell, the only way to know is by checking the Task.TaskSubtype field, but that field is only populated after the task has been inserted. Is there any way to know if a task is an email before the task is inserted?

EDIT: I'm talking about Tasks that are created in the following way: Contact record page > Email tab on the right > Compose email. When the email is sent, it causes a Task to be created, then an EmailMessage is created. My problem is that I don't want my TaskTrigger to do anything with the Task; I want my EmailMessage trigger to handle the EmailMessage instead. But I can't make my Task trigger ignore the task in the "before insert" section because there doesn't seem to be any way for it to know that the task is related to an email.

Comment: What about WhatId field? I see it can be populated with ListEmail standard object. Maybe if you have this field populated we can assume the Task comes from the email message.

Comment: Just tried it. It looks like the WhatId field points to the task's "Related To" record. (In my case, an Account.) So it doesn't seem to be helpful in determining if the task is an email.

Comment: And how is actually this Task created in a first place? I don't think there's a standard functionality which allows creating Tasks directly from an email.

Comment: @notmyf4ulty Contact record page > Email tab on the right > Compose email. When the email is sent, it causes a Task to be created, then an EmailMessage is created. My problem is that I don't want my TaskTrigger to do anything with the Task; I want my EmailMessage trigger to handle the EmailMessage instead. But I can't make my Task trigger ignore the task in the "before insert" section because there doesn't seem to be any way for it to know that the task is related to an email.

Comment: How about moving all your logic in after insert?